# Creating an array using data from a text file (NumPy)

Tags: python, arrays, file, text, numpy

I am trying to create an array with 2 columns and over 7000 rows (lots of data). The data I have is written as a text file and is formatted in two columns, each variable being separated by a space.
My biggest problem is that NumPy can't seem to find the file.

```
 1.  import numpy as np
 2.  np.fromfile(stardata.txt)
```

This returns:

```
NameError: name 'stardata' is not defined
```

I have checked the directory and everything seems to be in order. The file is in the correct directory.

My next problem is seeing if this would make a good array. I am guessing I might have to use `.reshape()` to make it look the way I want it to be. After that, I will be using the data to make a (Hertzsprung-Russell) diagram.

The full error message is here:

```
C:\Users\Petar\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):

    C:\Users\Petar\Desktop\test.py in <module>()
          1 import numpy as np
    ----> 2 np.fromfile(stardata.txt)

    NameError: name 'stardata' is not defined
```

Comment: After adding the quotes around the file name, it now says that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: I would recommend against using `np.fromfile` to load a text file.  `np.genfromtxt` is much improved.

Answer (score 3):

Your file name needs to be wrapped in quotes:

```
np.fromfile('stardata.txt')
```

Comment: It now says there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Where is `stardata.txt` in relation to the script you are executing and where you are executing it from? It sounds like you may just need the full path name in place to work.

Comment: Both the script and the text file are saved on my Desktop.

Comment: You need to be running the script from your desktop, then too. In your command window make sure you are at `C:\Users\<name>\Desktop` before executing `python <script>.py`.

Comment: When I ask it to list the directory, it states `C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\<filename.py>`. Maybe this is why it can't find the text file. How would I go about chaning the directory?